# What's the point of zeroing and testing a register, then conditionally jumping?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

In Rust code compiled with optimizations on Linux, this happens near the beginning of a function:

```
xor r10d, r10d
test r10, r10
jne .LBB32_5
```

This looks like it's just a no-op, as the `ZF` will always be 1. So why does the compiler find it helpful?

Comment: There is no point.  This is a missed optimization, or the result of inline asm or something.  If it's actual compiler output, I guess the `test` instruction can't be a branch target that can be reached some other way either.  I'd suggest creating a [mcve] of Rust source, and reporting it to https://bugs.llvm.org/ as a missed optimization bug.

Comment: Thanks. I'm happy to accept this as an answer if you post it. And yes, this is straight from the output of `cargo rustc --release -- --emit asm -C "llvm-args=-x86-asm-syntax=intel"`.

Comment: Without any corresponding Rust code, it's barely a real question.  It doesn't really need to be a Q&A on SO, just an LLVM or `rustc` bug.

Comment: Found a bug: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/72343